# Placing repository impl in not base-package

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I wan't separate my custom repository implementation from domain package. And, probablym some common interfaces. For example I want have structure like

```
  com
       domain
            Foo
            FooRepository
       common
            Bar
       persistence
            BarImpl

interface FooRepository extends Bar{}

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.domain" /> // smt else?
```

How I should config this?

Comment: what's the problem? It should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automatic pickup of the repository class only works if you place it in the very same package and use either the default postfix or define the suffix to use manually. So in your scenario you'd have to place a `FooRepositoryImpl` into the `domain` package. You can customize the suffix using the `repository-impl-postfix` attribute. If you'd like to place the implementation into another package you can declare the custom implementation bean manually using `fooRepositoryImpl` as bean id. The class can then reside in any package you want.

I assume that `Bar` is the interface containing the custom method declarations. Actually we recommend putting both the custom repository interface and implementation into the very same package and make it package protected to avoid it being available to clients individually. This way, all the clients actually see is the unified repository interface containing query methods and manually implemented ones.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I don't believe that putting the custom implementation with domain repository is good approach. I believe that there should be other way to declare implementation.